# How to copy files from one directory to another so that only new files are copied?

Tags: directory, directory-structure, file-copy

How would it be possible to copy all new contents from one directory to another so that only new files are copied from the source directory (both directories have the same naming tree). For example, here is the layout of directory A:

```
/dirA
     a.php
     b.txt
     subdirA1/
              readme.txt
              config
              source_file1.c

/dirB
     c.php
     subdirA1/
              readme.txt
```

at the end **dirB** should have all the new files in **dirA**. Assume that there are only new files in **dirA** and its sub directories. The result should be the union of the two directories:

```
/dirB
     a.php
     b.txt
     c.php
     subdirA1/
              readme.txt
              config                  
              source_file1.c
```

I have tried using cp -ra:

```
cp -ra dirA/* dirB/
```

but **dirB** is completely overwritten by **dirA**.

Comment: Did you checkout rsync?

Comment: Yep, it worked rsync -a dirA/ dirB :P

Comment: @Sebi `rsync -a dirA/ dirB/` overwrites the files in `dirB` with files by the same name from `dirA`, just like `cp -a`. What you're looking for is `rsync -a --ignore-existing`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) was designed exactly to solve this problem:

```
[$]> rsync -av --ignore-existing dirA/ dirB/
```

Comment: Er, yes, it is, but you have to use the right option!

Comment: Oops!  That's what I get for being quick about things and not testing them out.